# Is $\lg^{-1}n = (\lg n)^{-1}$?

Tags: functions, notation, logarithms, inverse

Today my professor said that $\lg^{-1}(n)=\lg(n)^{-1}$. As I'm used to know, $\lg^{-1}(n)$ denotes the inverse function ($2^n$) and $\lg(n)^{-1}$ the reciprocal (inverse number) $(\frac{1}{\lg(n)})$. Is there a situation where this notation may fail?

Comment: The inverse number notation is not the way to interpret the function raised to negative one rather your professor is telling you to treat a function raised to a negative one power is an inverse function

Comment: Situations where it will fail?  Nearly always!  Indeed it's a good problem to find out when it is *true*.  $2^n = 1/lg n $ means $1/2^n = lg n $ so $\sqrt [2^n] {2} = n$ so n^{2^n}=2$.  Then almost NEVER happens.

Comment: 0r did you mean to say your professor told you they are NOT equal.  What do you mean the notation might fail?  The sad news is that you will find *many* texts where this is not consistant.

Comment: @fleablood Offtopic, the professor obviously explained that in their lectures $\lg^{-1}(n)$ was to be understood as $(\lg n)^{-1}=\frac1{\lg n}$.

Comment: Did, you may be right, but your use of "obvious" differs from mine.  They way I read the post I thought it "obviously" meant the professor was making the absurd statement inverse = reciprical.  It never occured to me the professor was defining notation.

Comment: @fleablood Maybe start from the hypothesis that the professor is not making absurd statements but rather trying to teach mathematics and that they do it at least half competently? And then, if this hypothesis does not prove fruitful, turn to other interpretations... (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are two *different* concepts that are both commonly written as $f^n(x)$:

1. **Iteration** of the function $f$, in which for example $f^3(x)$ means $f(f(f(x))$.
2. **Pointwise power**, in which $f^3(x)$ means $f(x)\cdot f(x)\cdot f(x)$.

Each of these make independent sense -- the first of these concepts is exponentiation in the monoid of function and function composition, whereas the second is exponentiation in the ring of functions with pointwise addition and multiplication, and both of these structures are important and common.

In the particular case $n=-1$, the *iteration* concept leads to $f^{-1}(x)$ meaning the inverse function of $f$ -- that is, $f^{-1}(x)$ is the $y$ such that $f(y)=x$; whereas the pointwise power leads to $f^{-1}(x)$ meaning $\frac{1}{f(x)}$.

When one encounters a $f^n(x)$, one simply needs **either** to guess from the context which of the two meanings appear to make sense, **or** to be told explicitly by the writer which of them he intends to use. The latter of these was what your professor was doing when he *defined* that he's going to use $\lg^{-1}(x)$ in the sense of $\frac{1}{\lg x}$ rather than as the inverse function. This can be a useful choice to make if you're going to meet a lot of reciprocals of logarithms, especially since the inverse function already has the nice short notation $10^x$ anyway.